# How to pass a 2D array and vector from C# to python?

Tags: python, c#, parameter-passing

I want to pass a 2D array and a 1D vector to python script and receive the output in a 1D vector in C#. So far, I have followed this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=g1VWGdHRkHs&feature=emb_logo

This only shows how to pass strings to python.

**Update:**

I am incorporating @Danon 's method. So far I have this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            List<double> lst = a.ToList();

            string jsona = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(lst);


            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.FileName = @"C:\Users\lavni\Python\Python38\python.exe";

                var script = @"D:\test.py";

                psi.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", script, jsona);
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
                psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

                var errors = "";
                var results = "";

                using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
                {
                    errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                    results = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

                    Console.WriteLine("Errors");
                    Console.WriteLine(errors);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Results");
                    Console.WriteLine(results);

                }

            Console.Read();

        }
```

I have following python test.py. This just multiplies the vector by 5 and receives output in a string:

```
import sys
import json
import numpy as np

data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
res = np.array(data)
res = res*5

print(res)
```

Now, I am able to pass a vector and receive output as string in C#. Now, the question is can I receive the output as a list in C# instead of string. Plus, what to do in case of a 2D array. It cannot be passed as a list since I got error.

Answer (score 0):

Processes can only exchange data by execution parameters (commonly named `args` or `argv`) or by standard input (stdio); and the ran process can only return data in a form of standard output (stdout), standard error (stderr) or exit code (between 0-255).

So you will have to serialize your 2d array and 1d vector to some format that both c# and python can read. It can be any binary data, but I'd suggest you pass your JSON as a standard input to python script, and the python script could output JSON on the standard output, you can read and parse in c#.

Example of running python script with different types of data:

```
python myfile.py data # passing data as execution parameters
```

or

```
echo "data" | python myfile.py  # passing data on standard input
```

PS: To write to standard output in python you can just use `print()`.

Edit: In the YouTube video, the guys passes the values by execution arguments (3:52). If you want to follow that convention, instead of passing

```
psi.Arguments = $"\"{script}\" \"{start}\"";
```

convert your list to Json:

```
string jsonString= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(yourList);
```

and pass that json as an argument

```
psi.Arguments = $"\"{script}\" \"{jsonString}\"";
```

Then you will have to decode the JSON in your python script.

Comment: Can you give a basic example so that I can understand?